# Refresh pickerView to row0 with button press

Tags: button, view, ibaction, picker

I am having trouble refreshing all 7 components of my pickerView to row[0] with a button press. I have the Delegate and DataSource connected, and have defined UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource. I have tried these inputs under my IBAction Button.

```
[pickerView reloadAllComponents()]
```

and

```
pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
```

Here is some of the pickerView code.The bottom section is the beginning of a long switch I used for label inputs. I'm using an array, and my pickerView has 7 components.This part works perfectly.

```
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent      
     component: Int) -> String! {
     return data[row]
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, 
     forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
     let string = data[row]
     return NSAttributedString(string: data[row], atributes:
           [NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.whiteColor()])
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, 
     inComponent: Int) {
     var item1 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)]
     var item2 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(1)]
     var item3 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(2)]
     var item4 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(3)]
     var item5 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(4)]
     var item6 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(5)]
     var item7 = data[pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(6)]
```

@IBAction func ClearButton is the button I wish to click to reload my pickerView to [row]0. When I use the code reloadAllComponents(), and press the ClearButton, the other actions of my ClearButton work perfectly, but the components to not reload to [row]0. Here is my @IBAction ClearButton code.

```
@IBAction func ClearButton(sender: AnyObject) {

     textField1.text = ""
     textField2.text = ""
     textField3.text = ""
     textField4.text = ""
     textField5.text = ""
     textField6.text = ""
     textField7.text = ""
     myLabel.text = "Please input data"

     label1.text = "-"
     label2.text = "-"
     label3.text = "-"
     label4.text = "-"
     label5.text = "-"
     label6.text = "-"
     label7.text = "-"

     pickerView.reloadAllComponents()

     }
```

Note: Yes, I've used [pickerView reloadAllComponents()]. Willing to try anything, doesn't have to be conventional. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Just had to type the following under @IBAction myButton:

```
self.myPickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
```

There's so much outdated, obsolete information on this website. However I do appreciate the relevant help when I find it.